# Python hashlib MD5 inconsistency from Python 2.x to Python 3?

Tags: python, md5

The following is being run on python 2.4 and produces the following hash:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import md5
id=76561198302409766
temp = ""
for i in range(8):
        temp +=  chr((id & 0xFF))
        id >>= 8
m = md5.new("BE"+temp)
print m.hexdigest()
```

This is the converted code for Python 3:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3.3 -B 
import hashlib
id = 76561198302409766
print ("Python 2.4 output:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa")
m = hashlib.md5()
temp = ""
for i in range(8):
    temp += chr((id & 0xFF))
    id >>= 8
m.update("BE".encode('utf-8')+temp.encode('utf-8'))
print ("%s" % m.hexdigest())
```

This produces a totally different hash.  What can I do to fix it so that it produces the same hash as the previous script?

Comment: These two codes are not identical by the way. You are encoding `temp`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Convert it correctly.

```
import hashlib
id = 76561198302409766
print ("Python 2.4 output:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa")
m = hashlib.md5()
temp = bytearray()
for i in range(8):
    temp.append(id & 0xFF)
    id >>= 8
m.update(b"BE" + temp)
print ("%s" % m.hexdigest())
```

...

```
$ python3 hash.py
Python 2.4 output:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa
a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa
```

Or write it correctly in the first place.

```
import hashlib
import struct

id = 76561198302409766
print ("Python 2.4 output:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa")
m = hashlib.md5()
temp = struct.pack('<Q', id)
m.update(b"BE" + temp)
print ("%s" % m.hexdigest())
```

...

```
$ python2 hash2.py
Python 2.4 output:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa
a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa
$ python3 hash2.py
Python 2.4 output:  a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa
a1e48607773b80c62b80af2b6358c4fa
```